# busybox doesn't work on marshmallow

Tags: busybox

The system builtin `ip` command works correctly with:

```
# ip route show table wlan0
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx dev wlan0  proto static  scope link
```

But `busybox ip` doesn't:

```
# busybox ip route show table wlan0
ip: invalid argument 'wlan0' to 'table'
```

Looks like `busybox` failed to read some system settings.

1. So what's wrong here?
2. When tried to uninstall, the `Busybox Free` app froze. Is it safe to manually remove `busybox` and its symlinks in adb shell?

Comment: If they are in `/system/xbin/` they are almost safe to remove.